# Commons-like HTTP server-side utilities?

Tags: java, http

I'm a big fan of the Apache commons libraries, since they tend to cover a lot of utilities I would normally have to write myself. Recently I've started working on a server-side project and I'm finding a lot of cases where the default classes are missing obvious functionality:

### [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

- Needs a `Cookie getCookie(String name)` method.
- Needs an easy way to get request URL info (besides calling `getContextURL()` and parsing it yourself)
- Something to simplify basic and digest authentication would be nice

I suspect I'll find more of these as I work on this project.

These seem like the sorts of things that are bound to be in a library somewhere. Does such a library exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People rarely write web apps on bare Servlets nowadays. There are some great web frameworks around that make a lot of things a lot easier, including the things you mention in your question.

I would recommend you have a look at [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

Comment: Yeah I'm a big fan of Spring and it's annotations. Unfortunately, it's not an option for this project. I'm looking for something more lightweight.